# How to create private ssh RSA key from text file on mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, rsa, private-key

I requested a client's sys admin to give me access to their AWS account.. so he sent me an email that looks like this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXX
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And he said that the password for the private key is (let's say) `1234`

I'm not exactly sure how to create an actual private key file out of this text.. If i simply save it to a `.pem` file and use it in the ssh command like so:

```
ssh -i private_key_file.pem -p 2501 user@host.ip
```

it prompts me for the password.. and when I enter `1234` it rejects the password.

Further, If I simply try to change the password on the private key like so:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f private_key_file.pem
```

it rejects the password given to me by the system admin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *is* a private key, stored in OpenSSL format (which OpenSSH also uses). You can verify the contents using `openssl rsa -noout -text < yourfile.pem`.

If it rejects the password, then usually the password is simply wrong.